# Prove that $\{(a,b): a,b\in \Bbb Q \land a<b \}$ is a base for the euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I dont have a clue about that. If I take the definition of base of a topology it says:

> A collection of open sets $\cal B$ is a base of a topology $\tau$ if any open set is a union of elements of this collection.

So I dont know how is possible that for any interval $(c,d)$ with $c,d\in\Bbb R$ exists some $\bigcup_{i,j\in I}(a_i,b_j)=(c,d)$ where $a_i,b_j\in\Bbb Q$. To me this is impossible, imagine that $c$ and $d$ are irrational numbers... how I can compose by union of interval defined by rationals an interval as $(c,d)$?

Some hint? Some big mistake in my formulation? Any help is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: How do open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ look like? Also note that $(a,b) = \cup_{n \ge 1} (p_n,q_n)$, where, $p_n$ and $q_n$ are rational sequences in $(a,b)$ converging to $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$.

Given $(c,d)$, there's a rational $s_1\in (c+\frac {d-c} 2, d)$, then a rational $s_2 \in  (\max(s_1, c+\frac {3(d-c)} 4), d)$, ... thus, a strictly increasing sequence of rationals $(s_n)$ with $(c+d)/2 < s_1 < s_2 < ... < d = \lim_n s_n$. (Concluding that the entire *sequence* $(s_n)$ exists implicitly uses the Axiom of Dependent Choice.)

Similarly, there's a strictly decreasing sequence of rationals $(r_n)$ with $\lim_n r_n = c < ... < r_2 < r_1 < (c+d)/2$.

Let $I_n = (r_n, s_n)$,  $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $(c,d) = \bigcup_{n} I_n$.

Comment: Ty @BrianO, I will accept this answer because I see it more complete that the others. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for that. PS I edited the answer slightly, it wasn't quite right: I added $\max(s_1, ...)$ to ensure that $s_n \uparrow$. The sequences still converged, and the conclusion was true, but the sequences weren't necessarily monotone. Not that it matters, really (all elements were in $(c,d)$), but I said they were, & they can be :)

Answer (score 3):

Every real number is a limit of an increasing/decreasing sequence of rational numbers. Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of rational numbers $<d$ decreasing to $c$ and let $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of rational numbers $>c$ increasing to $d$. Then

$$(c,d)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (x_n,y_n).$$

Comment: Oh, I understand... I need to put a union of sets where the limits are some kind of infinite sequence that define any real number. Yes, I had this in my mind but I dont see the way to make the sequence. I see clear now, ty very much.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you just need that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and that for every open set on $\mathbb R$ there a subset included of the form you stated.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ form a base of the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$.

In general if $\mathcal B$ serves as base for some topology on $X$ and $Y\subseteq X$ then $\{Y\cap B:B\in\mathcal B\}$ serves as a base of the relative topology on $Y$.